# Calling DevicePolicyManager inside AlarmReciever

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am trying to use DevicePolicyManager to lock my phone within an alarmmanger receiver. I just cant get the syntax right, probably doing something stupid ... could someone please show me the error of my ways ?

Thanks

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String Password = "LOCK";
    String UnlockPassword = "UNLOCK";

    ComponentName mDeviceAdmin;
    private DevicePolicyManager mDPM;


 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     gcmaction();

     Intent lockintent = new Intent(context, CurfewSetActivity.class);
     lockintent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
     context.startActivity(intent);

 }

 private void gcmaction() {

      Log.i(TAG,"gcm lock action method started");
```

its these next two lines that are giving errors (The method getSystemService(String) is undefined for the type AlarmReceiver)

```
       mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
       mDeviceAdmin = new ComponentName(this, AdminReceiver.class);

       boolean active = mDPM.isAdminActive(mDeviceAdmin);
       if (active) {
       mDPM.resetPassword(Password,DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
       mDPM.lockNow();



        }
      else Log.i(TAG,"Not an admin");
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
```

with

```
mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
```

`getSystemService` is a method of `Context` class so you need an object of that class to access it.